# Probability problem with a function $f(x)$ and exponential distribution

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, exponential-distribution

I have the following problem which I can't figure out how to solve it.

Let $a∈R$ and $Y$ be an exponentially distributed random variable with parameter 1.

Furthermore let $f(x):=x^2−ax+Y$ for $x∈R$. Calculate in dependence of $a$ the probability that $f$ has at least one real root.

For which $a$ is this probability greater than $0.5$?

I don't know how to start. Do I need to write insted of Y $e^{-x}$ in $f(x)$ and than work with $f(x)$ as a density function?

Comment: I would start by first inspecting the existence of roots of $f(x) = x^2 - ax + b$, you could do this by looking at the discriminant. This will give the intervals for which values of b the equation has roots (intervals will be in terms of a). Then you could use your probability distribution to calculate the probability of falling within these intervals.

Comment: This is essentially $P(f(x)\le 0)$

Comment: @Paul $P(f(x)\leq 0)$ might not be the best way to write it as it does not inform us about the dependence on $Y$. It's better to write $P(\{Y=y :\, \exists x_{0}\in\Bbb{R} \,\text{such that}\, x_{0}^{2}-ax_{0}+y\leq 0\})$ . Which is the same as $P(a^{2}-4Y\geq 0)$ which is a much compact and short notation as the theory of quadratic equations and basic facts about parabolas tell us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First consider $f(x) = x^2 - ax + b$, then we know this has roots if

$$ a^2 - 4b \geq 0 \implies a^2 \geq 4b \implies b \leq a^2/4 .$$

So the probability of having a root is

$$ P(\text{root}) = P(Y \leq a^2 / 4). $$

So integrating the exponential probability distribution from $0$ to $a^2/4$ will give the probability. Setting this equal to $1/2$ will give the boundary for $a$.

Comment: Just to be precise(although it wont make a difference in the answer) . A real quadratic polynomial has atleast one real root if $\text{discriminant}\geq 0$ . The strict inequality is for distinct real roots.

Comment: Thank you very much ;)

Comment: Indeed, the strict inequalities were a bit sloppy. I edited the answer